# Using gl_FragColor vs. out vec4 color?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

There seems to be a lot of ambiguity about `gl_FragColor` being deprecated.  For example, it is missing in the [GLSL 4.40 specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf), but it is included in the [GLSL 4.60 specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf).

What is the safest, most compatible, most supported strategy?  Using `gl_FragColor` or defining a shader output like `out vec4 color`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, `gl_FragColor` is deprecated. You should use the following syntax:

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 diffuseColor;
```

It is included in the GLSL 4.60 spec under the section `7.1.7. Compatibility Profile Built-In Language Variables`. That means, if you create a core context this variable will not be available.

Comment: you didn't specify what "out vec4 color" means, you instead talking about something else called "diffuseColor" which i don't know what it is either

Comment: diffuseColor is literally just a variable name. All OpenGL cares about is that there be a vec4 at output layout location 0

Answer (score 8):

If you would  read the the [GLSL 4.40 specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf) carefully, then you would find  `gl_FragCoord` in chapter *"7.1.1 Compatibility Profile Built-In Language Variables"*, as it is in the [GLSL 4.60 specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf).

> The following fragment output variables are available in a fragment shader when using the **compatibility profile**:
>
> ```
> out vec4 gl_FragColor;
> out vec4 gl_FragData[gl_MaxDrawBuffers];
> ```
>
> Writing to `gl_FragColor` specifies the fragment color that will be used by the subsequent fixed functionality pipeline. If subsequent fixed functionality consumes fragment color and an execution of the fragment shader executable does not write a value to `gl_FragColor` then the fragment color consumed is undefined.

This means you can't use `gl_FragColor`, in an [OpenGL Core profile Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#Context_types), because it is deprecated, but it would still be available in a compatibility profile.

The modern way of writing to the output buffers from a fragment shader, is to declare [user-defined output variables](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Outputs) and to use [Layout Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Fragment_shader_buffer_output).