# OpenGL ES - Fragment shader version

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader

I just got started with OpenGL ES on Android, and I can't seem to specify the version of OpenGL to use in the fragment shader.

This version compiles and runs successfully

```c
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

But this doesn't

```c
#version 300 es
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

I've tried multiple version, with and without "es". The only thing that works is `version 100`.
Weirdly, I've added `#version 300 es` in the vertex shader, which works fine.

The code is compiled with

```kotlin
fun createProgram() {
        program = GLES32.glCreateProgram()
        val vertexShader = loadShader(GLES32.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode)
        val fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES32.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode)
        GLES32.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader)
        GLES32.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader)
        GLES32.glLinkProgram(program)
        GLES32.glUseProgram(program)
}

fun loadShader(type: Int, shaderCode: String): Int {
    return GLES32.glCreateShader(type).also { shader ->
        // add the source code to the shader and compile it
        GLES32.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode)
        GLES32.glCompileShader(shader)

        val successPointer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Int.SIZE_BYTES).asIntBuffer()
        GLES32.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES32.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, successPointer)
        if (successPointer[0] != 0) {
            println("Couldn't compile: ${successPointer[0]} ${GLES32.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader)}")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should show your Android app code for compiling the shader. Note that Android has specific classes for GL ES versions: [GLES10](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES10), [GLES20](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES20), [GLES30](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES30), etc.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited. I'm using GLES32, and specified `android:glEsVersion="0x00030000"` in the Android Manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it ! [`gl_FragColor` was deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459596/using-gl-fragcolor-vs-out-vec4-color) and should be replaced by a defined `out`. This only applies for version 3, hence the error when compiled with a later version...

As a side note, the correct way to get the GL_COMPILE_STATUS is

```kotlin
val compiled = IntArray(1)
GLES32.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES32.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0)
if (compiled[0] != GLES32.GL_TRUE) {
    println("Couldn't compile: ${compiled[0]} ${GLES32.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader)}")
} else {
    println("Successfully compiled!")
}
```